# How do to filter in many to many relationships in Flask SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am building a flask app which hosts lectures of a school.
I have to restrict subjects to students by classes. This means to display subjects on subject page which are assigned to a Class.
I have a Many to Many relationship between Classes Model and Subjects Model.

#### The Classes Model

```
class Class(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__="clases"

    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    campus=db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    grade=db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False)
    section=db.Column(db.String(1), nullable=False)
    clas_incharge=db.Column(db.String(46))
    students=db.relationship("User", backref="clas", lazy="dynamic")
    subjects=db.relationship("Subject", secondary=sbjcts, lazy="dynamic", backref=db.backref("clases", lazy=True))
```

#### The Subject Model

```
class Subjects(db.Model):

    __tablename__="subjects"

    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)
    description=db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    lectures=db.relationship("Lecture", backref="subject", lazy="dynamic")
    resources=db.relationship("Resource", backref="subject", lazy="dynamic")
```

### The Association table

```
sbjcts=db.Table("sbjcts",
        db.Column("clas_id", db.ForeignKey("clases.id")),
        db.Column("subject_id", db.ForeignKey("subjects.id")))
```

What I want is how can I make a query which returns the subjects with the particular class assigned
The condition here is the class which i would provide to get subjects
**Note:** Multiple classes can have the same subjects.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.session.query(Subjects).join(Subjects.clases).filter(Class.id==1).all()
```

The above should work.

Your `Class` model defines the relationship to `Subjects`. You also add a `backref` here, which essentially adds the attribute `clases` to the `Subjects` mapper that defines the relationship `Subject` has to `Class` from the perspective of `Subject`.

We can leverage this in defined relationship in our query while still providing a filter.

Also just to be clear, the above query will return all Subjects that have the given Class. If you look into one of these returned Subject ORM objects it will list all the 'clases' it has.